# If a fey steals a character's name, how can they steal it back?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore

I want to run a oneshot where the names of the whole party have been stolen by fey, somehow.

I don't know fey lore, so I'm  asking for ways they might get their names back.

- Would they need to barter with the fey, or can they just kill it?
- If a fey says the name, will they be able to steal it back?
- Can it be stored somewhere, like inside a bottle?
- What happens to a character whose name was stolen?

I'm not familiar with fey lore, so if someone can explain it to me, that'd be very helpful.

Comment: It would help to provide some context for your question. Are you the player in this situation, and your character's name was stolen?  If you're the GM, what are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there'd be guidance for this in Wild Beyond The Witchlight and/or Domains of Delight.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: What does stealing a name even mean?  Does that mean the characters can't use their names any more?  People don't recognize them?  How did it get stolen?  Even imagining we COULD have any useful answer, other than opinion, we'd certainly need to know the mechanics of what your plan is.

Comment: I found a decent [blog post](https://the-fae-folk.tumblr.com/post/645781091538649088/what-actually-happens-if-the-fae-take-your-name) about the folklore it's based on.

Comment: @Jack the meme-ified version is a Fae asking a mortal "Can I have your name, please?" or something equally as specific. Traditionally it was more of a "if you tell the Fae your whole name" type of deal

Comment: I voted to close this recently because it lacks a bit of detail. If you are starting with the premise that a fey steals a name you need to tell us how and why, since either you should be using either a written rule or a homebrew one

Answer (score 11):

There is no canonical answer to this question.
There are no rules in 5e for stealing someone's name.

As the DM, you can make up rules for doing this, but then you'll also need to make up rules for how your players can get out of it.

Comment: Alright thanks, ill just figure it out then. If anyone has any ideas, I'd be glad to hear them

Comment: To be clear, there's no information in the lore at all about fae stealing names?

Answer (score 5):

### Fae, Faeries, Fey, Spirits taking names is a common myth across the world

I love this as an adventure hook!

When looking at the treatment of the Fae in 5e an excellent resource (for DMs) is The Wild Beyond the Witchlight, an adventure set in the Feywild.

Beyond that there are a number of cultural references upon which you can base such a plot hook.

#### The Wild Beyond the Witchlight

One potential set of story hooks involves:

> Lost Things of the characters that were taken when they were a child

which include:

> Ability to keep secrets, Ability to smile, Artistic creativity, Cherished doll or stuffed animal, Handwriting, Sense of direction, Sense of fashion, or Three inches of height

It also provides for a method behind this:

> For each character in the adventuring party, roll a d8 and consult the Lost Things table to determine what was stolen from that character. If a player doesn’t like their result, let them choose an option they prefer. You can swap out some of the entries on the Lost Things table with others that you or your players create, using the ones described below as models.

A character can resolve their personal hook by:

> The hags used each character’s lost thing to craft a magic item. By interacting with the magic item in a specific way (as described below), the character regains what they lost. The magic item otherwise functions normally.

It gives examples for the provided options and suggests the DM use them as a base for DM/player additions to these hooks.

#### Cultural References and Popular Culture

The Fae/Fey and the Feywild in D&D have been *heavily* influenced by Irish and Scottish mythology, with many of the Fey related creatures being lifted directly from these traditions.

Watch Spirited Away for inspiration.

##### Names have power in Celtic folklore

In Irish and Scottish mythology, to tell one of the fair folk your name was to give them power over you. The idea of literal theft of your name has come later from other sources. In Irish folklore you might want to look up the Sidhe or Aos Sí for inspiration. I'm not as familiar with the names in Scottish folklore (but they are very similar).

However, there is the somewhat related idea of the Changeling. In Celtic folklore the changeling is a wicked creature who steals children from their human parents, and replaces them with changeling children, for those parents to raise. In a way this is stealing the "name" of the child. Something similar could have happened to your characters, they may have literally been replaced on their native plane by a doppelgänger or changeling.

##### Spirited Away

In this (excellent) movie

> The protagonist Chihiro has the second kanji of her name taken away by the witch Yubaba, and becomes Sen, after she stumbles into the spirit world with her parents (and a bunch of other things happen). This is used as a means of control, and if she is unable to keep hold of and remember her name she will not be able to leave the world of the spirits.

#### What would I do as a DM?

I would have a powerful Fae have met the characters and upon learning their names use Modify Memory (or some power akin to that) to take it and assign them a new one, but leave them knowing their actual name has been taken. This would leave the characters with an intense drive to find who or what had taken their name and retrieve it.

The Fae then uses the "power" drawn from their suffering, to infuse a maguffin, which of the characters retrieve they reverse the effects of the memory change. Each character might have a separate one or it might be a combined one (maybe enabling the Fae to move to the Material Plane as a native denizen while the characters don't know their names).

While they remain in the Feywild, time doesn't pass for them, but if they set foot on the Material Plane again without knowing their names, they will wither and die in an instant. (This bit is robbed directly from one of the stories about the Tuatha De Dannan).

The Fae could be bargained with, but something equally valuable would need to be offered in return for a name. If no agreement can be struck then the only option is to fight. If an agreement is struck then it is magically enforced and binding.

Suitable alternatives might be:

- The promise of the name of someone they love
- A portion of their life lived (think the Weeping Angels from Dr Who)
- A skill they cherish which they can never retrieve or relearn (think thieves tools)
- etc

Comment: So much easier having your identity stolen in real life, just call the bank and cancel your cards

Comment: @SeriousBri indeed it is!

Comment: "In Irish and Scottisn mythology, to tell one of the Fair Folk your name was to give them power over you" - Can you cite any authentic fairy tale where this was the case? I suspect this to be a 21st century invention, specifically from Spirited Away.

Comment: @causative it absolutely predates Spirited Away (which is based on Japanese folklore). I grew up and live in Ireland and the idea of power in names was present during my childhood (long prior to Spirited Away being released). Some examples from "The Fairy Faith in Celtic Countries" (1910): Page 137: "If a fairy’s proper name was discovered, the fairy to whom it belonged felt baffled", Page 144: "[...] women of the Tylwyth Teg made their appearance in the pasture and, calling the cows by name, led the whole herd into the lake, and with them disappeared beneath its waters"

Comment: @illustro Your first example is a name granting *humans* power over the *fae*, not the other way around. This is also what we see in Rumplestiltskin; the opposite of having power over names, names are a fae's weakness. Your second example is power over cows, and it may not even be magical power - it may simply be cows that come when their name is called because the farmer trained them that way.

Comment: If you're right you should be able to find at least one example of specifically a fae stealing a *human's* name, and using it to gain clearly magical power over the human, happening in a historical fairy tale. If you can't do that, then just stories that involve names and fae in some other manner do not support your case.

Comment: There's a good reason why we would find fairy tales where a human uses a fae's name to gain power over the fae (and there are several of those), but not the reverse. Fairy tales were told to children and the parents would have wanted to give the child a lesson that knowing someone else's name could be useful. But the parent wouldn't want to teach the child to hide their name from others, as that would be antisocial.

Comment: @causative I've not done an exhaustive search (I don't have time), but I was responding specifically to your assertion "I suspect this to be a 21st century invention, specifically from Spirited Away.". It's not. This idea is also present in Egyptian mythology (see the story of Ra, Isis and the Snake). The idea that there is power in names (or more specifically *true names*)

Comment: I also did not say that in irish and scottish folklore that the faeries *stealing* your name gave them power over you. In fact I said in the sentence after the one you quoted in your original comment "The idea of literal theft of your name has come later from other sources."

Comment: As to folk tales of people hiding their names from faeries: https://sacred-texts.com/neu/eng/efft/efft40.htm (this specific one is from England I believe, but there are equivalents from Ireland & Scotland ("The door opened, and a strange creature strode in. He was tall and hairy, with a livid covering on his face instead of skin. He advanced towards the woman and asked her name. She replied in Gaelic, "Mise mi Fhin ""Me myself."" https://www.gutenberg.org/files/56034/56034-h/56034-h.htm#pb167)

Comment: You said, "In Irish and Scottish mythology, to tell one of the Fair Folk your name was to give them power over you." It is this claim that I objected to when I said "I suspect this is a 21st century invention." You still haven't given any example of a human telling one of the Fair Folk their name and as a result the Fair Folk gaining (magic) power over them. Ra and Isis were not humans, so that story is not an example of a magical being stealing a *human's* name, and nor were they Irish or Scottish. The Mise mi Fhin story is the human playing a trick with no suggestion of name magic.

Answer (score -5):

### A character whose true name has been discovered can be summoned and mind-controlled.

The section of the *Monster Manual* on [demons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-d#Demons) contains a sidebar on "Demon True Names" (p. 53):

> Though demons all have common names, every demon lord and every demon of type 1 through 6 has a true name that it keeps secret. A demon can be forced to disclose its true name if charmed, and ancient scrolls and tomes are said to exist that list the true names of the most powerful demons.
>
> A mortal who learns a demon’s true name can use powerful summoning magic to call the demon from the Abyss and exercise some measure of control over it. However, most demons brought to the Material Plane in this manner do everything in their power to wreak havoc or sow discord and strife.

For example, the [*summon greater demon*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/summon-greater-demon) spell description states (XGtE, p. 166):

> You utter foul words, summoning one demon from the chaos of the Abyss. You choose the demon’s type, which must be one of challenge rating 5 or lower, such as a shadow demon or a barlgura. The demon appears in an unoccupied space you can see within range, and the demon disappears when it drops to 0 hit points or when the spell ends.
>
> [...]
>
> At the end of each of the demon’s turns, it makes a Charisma saving throw. The demon has disadvantage on this saving throw if you say its true name. On a failed save, the demon continues to obey you.

There's nothing saying this applies to mortals, but it wouldn't fit your game if it didn't, so you can say it does. In earlier editions, there was an idea of true names which did also apply to mortals.

The fey can summon the players, and get advantage on any mind control. They might summon the players to help handle a dispute or fight for them, like players might summon a demon.

The fey can hold their name in their memory, or in a bottle. You'd need custom magic to do this; there's nothing in their lore that says they can do this. If you want particular mechanics, you could have a custom magical item that lets them hold their true names, protecting it from rival fey who would steal it.

Comment: If a fey steals your name, it's not your name any more.

Comment: I was suggesting they use the existing true name lore that demons have, not that they follow the name stealing lore that isn't in dnd.

Comment: They're not really comparable; *learning* someone's true name is not the same as *stealing* someone's true name.

Comment: OP established that their names have already been stolen in the background of the story. However they learnt the names, presumably it involved stealing. I didn't make the prompt, that is what op asked.