# Do fae need to ask for a name in a specific way?

Tags: dnd-5e

I'm well aware that as DM I can make the world how I see fit, but in this case I don't want to change well established functions like *how a fae steals a name*. Well versed characters would know how it works, and I can't explain that to them ahead of time that it works differently in my world.

Does a fae need to phrase the question in a way that implies possession like the usual "Can I have your name?" or could they simply ask "What's your name?"

Comment: I wasn’t aware that this was a well established function. Is this something that is explored in detail in older editions? I’ve only played 5e, and didn’t even know this was a thing.

Comment: By fae do you mean fey-type creatures? fae isn't a monster or type I'm familiar with in dnd 5e.

Comment: Related: [If a fey steals a character's name, how can they steal it back?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/196273/if-a-fey-steals-a-characters-name-how-can-they-steal-it-back)

Comment: For the record, I'm not familiar either.  That's why I'm asking the question. Is there established lore around this?

Comment: I've never heard of *anything* about stealing names in D&D. There's been some 'truenaming' stuff in prior editions, but even then it's all about *knowing* true names, not stealing them as in removing the name from the creature that previously had it.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym Just look up "fae name stealing memes" it is definitely a thing.

Comment: I'm not saying no DM has ever done it, just saying I've never heard of it. There are no official mechanics I've seen, and it's never happened in any game I've played. There really isn't even any folklore about fae stealing names as far as I know -- lots about "don't tell them your real name" but that's about how names have power, not letting them actually take away your name. Maybe it's something relatively new coming out of the urban fantasy genre, I dunno.

Comment: I've rolled back to revision 2. The title change was an entirely different question from the one that was asked. (Which is why I rejected the suggested edit in review for "conflicts with author's intent")

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### There is not

There is no RAW game mechanic or official lore in 5e regarding how a name would be stolen or traded, or what it means to have your name taken from you. There is a suggested plot hook in Wild Beyond the Witchlight where players have had some intangible stolen from them. There are also a ton of real world myths from around the world about stolen names.

There is references to the power of *true names* of things in printed material. For instance, *[summon greater demon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/summon-greater-demon)* contains a line that says, "The demon has disadvantage on this saving throw if you say its true name" There was a UA Wizard of Onomancy that powers related to true names that didn't make print.

Comment: You even remembered the Onomancy, have my upvote!!!

Comment: I'm not well read in folktales, but in modern fiction it seems that fae are more interested in deals and trades than outright theft. In Wild Beyond the Witchlight, there are several instances where intangibles are traded, including the primary plothook where something was taken as penalty for entering the carnival without a ticket. For consistency, I would expect that a player's true name couldn't be taken without agency and without receiving something in return. If a name is given mistakenly, it might create an obligation for the fae to reciprocate.

Comment: Trades and deals are more common than theft but fey can and do also steal. They are devils looking to get people to sign away their soul, but they do appreciate winning a negotiation, especially when the other party doesn't know they lost, yet. I think I would also make the taking of a name require the player giving it up, even if they don't know what they just agreed to.

Answer (score -4):

For name stealing in lore, there's a special name the NPC has which can be stolen. See lore on demons say.

The section of the *Monster Manual* on [demons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-d#Demons) contains a sidebar on "Demon True Names" (p. 53):

> Though demons all have common names, every demon lord and every demon of type 1 through 6 has a true name that it keeps secret. A demon can be forced to disclose its true name if charmed, and ancient scrolls and tomes are said to exist that list the true names of the most powerful demons.
>
> A mortal who learns a demon’s true name can use powerful summoning magic to call the demon from the Abyss and exercise some measure of control over it. However, most demons brought to the Material Plane in this manner do everything in their power to wreak havoc or sow discord and strife.

For example, the [*summon greater demon*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/summon-greater-demon) spell description states (XGtE, p. 166):

> You utter foul words, summoning one demon from the chaos of the Abyss. You choose the demon’s type, which must be one of challenge rating 5 or lower, such as a shadow demon or a barlgura. The demon appears in an unoccupied space you can see within range, and the demon disappears when it drops to 0 hit points or when the spell ends.
>
> [...]
>
> At the end of each of the demon’s turns, it makes a Charisma saving throw. The demon has disadvantage on this saving throw if you say its true name. On a failed save, the demon continues to obey you.

If you wanted to homebrew name stealing rules, there would presumably be some sort of unique true name that people had. This could be their full name said from their lips or their mother's lips, something in an ancient primordial language, or whatever you wanted that was separate from just, their publicly known name that anyone could steal.